# How to create an odbc string connection in an excel spreadsheet to make it portable instead of setting up an odbc connection on every computer?

Tags: microsoft-excel, postgresql, odbc

I'm setting up an excel reporting using Excel 2013 for that.

The spreadsheet is retrieving data, through an odbc connection that I need to set on every computer in order to retrieve the data.

I tried to change the following:

> Data > Query > Change the property of the connection chain

This is the connection string

> DSN=BI_AZURE;DATABASE=dw;SERVER=mydb.postgres.database.azure.com;PORT=5432;UID=sqladmin@username;SSLmode=disable;ReadOnly=0;Protocol=7.4;FakeOidIndex=0;ShowOidColumn=0;RowVersioning=0;ShowSystemTables=0;ConnSettings=;Fetch=100;Socket=4096;UnknownSizes=0;MaxVarcharSize=255;MaxLongVarcharSize=8190;Debug=0;CommLog=0;Optimizer=0;Ksqo=1;UseDeclareFetch=0;TextAsLongVarchar=1;UnknownsAsLongVarchar=0;BoolsAsChar=1;Parse=0;CancelAsFreeStmt=0;ExtraSysTablePrefixes=dd_;LFConversion=1;UpdatableCursors=1;DisallowPremature=0;TrueIsMinus1=0;BI=0;ByteaAsLongVarBinary=0;UseServerSidePrepare=0;LowerCaseIdentifier=0;GssAuthUseGSS=0;XaOpt=1

Is there a way to remove the `DSN=BI_AZURE` and put a static string, that won't use the DSN and yet will be able to connect the reporting, to any machine, regardless if the odbc connection is existing?

Thanks.

Comment: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2044174-excel-2013-external-data-connection-how-to-embed-the-connection-string

Comment: `Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};Server=IP address;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;` Change driver if need. Add extra parameters if need. [PostgreSQL connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make sure you have an existing odbc driver in order to do this.

And tick the following box (mind the french system language)
[image]

Change your code with the following:

```
DRIVER={PostgreSQL UNICODE};DATABASE=dw;SERVER=mydb.postgres.database.azure.com;PORT=5432;UID=sqladmin@username;
```

And everything should be working.

[Connection string source](https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/)

[Helpful source](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2044174-excel-2013-external-data-connection-how-to-embed-the-connection-string)